# Do I need Dota 2 to redeem the free item I got?

Tags: steam, dota-2

I bought a mouse that comes with the Kantusa Sword, but I don't play Dota 2.

Is it possible for me to redeem the item even if I don't install Dota 2? I was hoping to sell it in the steam marketplace instead.

Comment: You don't need Dota2 to redeem a Dota2 item. When you input the code on Steam, it will create a Dota2 inventory for you on Steam as well, and then you can sell it on the marketplace.

Comment: Do you still have that sword :) ? I would love to buy it.

Comment: You couldnt hope to get more than cents for it on the market place, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Kantusa Sword is concidered as any other Steam product. You can find the steps to activate it [on the support page](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5414-TFBN-1352) :

- Launch the Steam client software and log into your Steam account.
- Click the Games Menu.
- Choose *Activate a Product on Steam...*

[image]

- Enter your Key when prompted and follow the instructions on screen.

[image]

Finish and the item should be added to your Steam inventory.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply redeem the key and then sell the item without ever launching the game. Just enter the key provided on the key activation menu and it should then be added to your Inventory where you can list it on the Community Market. If, after successful key activation, it does not appear in your Inventory under the Dota 2 section, then you may need to download the game (it's free) and launch it, but I'm almost certain this is unnecessary.